# .htaccess redirect if param value not portuguese-pt (FORCE WHMCS ONLY ONE LANG)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, regex

I need help to redirect URLs with multiple language codes to one with `.htaccess`. The following URLs should redirect:

- `https://example.com/cp/cart.php?a=add&pid=7&language=us`
- `https://example.com/cp/cart.php?a=add&pid=5&language=de`
- `https://example.com/cp/cart.php?language=nl`
- `https://example.com/cp/home.php?language=uk&test=a`

to

- `https://example.com/cp/cart.php?a=add&pid=7&language=portuguese-pt`
- `https://example.com/cp/cart.php?a=add&pid=5&language=portuguese-pt`
- `https://example.com/cp/cart.php?language=portuguese-pt`
- `https://example.com/cp/home.php?language=portuguese-pt&test=a`

**IMPORTENT** : Do not do anything if the URL does not contain a  "language" URL parameter.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your `.htaccess` file located? In the document root or the `cp` subdirectory? If not in `cp` are you OK with creating another `.htaccess` file in that subdirectory?

Comment: Does this rule only apply to URL-paths `/cp/cart.php` and `/cp/home.php`? Or could this apply to any URL-path?

Comment: @MrWhite my .htaccess file path is in cp folder . and i have alot file like home.php and cart.php. i need this for any url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my .htaccess file path is in cp folder. and i have alot file like home.php and cart.php. i need this for any url

To act on any URL-path then you could do something like the following near the top of the `/cp/.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?(language=)(?!portuguese-pt(?:&|$))[^&]*(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2portuguese-pt%3 [NE,R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^` is successful for any URL-path.

The preceding *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) matches the query string. It is only successful when the `language` URL parameter exists, but not equal to `portuguese-pt` (as determined by the negative-lookahead). The value of the `language` URL param is otherwise discarded.

We capture the parts of the query string that surround the `language` URL parameter *value*. These are saved in the following backreferences:

- `%1` / pattern `(.*&)?` - the part of the query string *before* the `language` URL parameter (if any). This includes the `&` delimiter before the `language` URL param.
- `%2` / pattern `(language=)` - captures the literal text `language=`. This must match to be successful. This simply saves repetition later.
- `%3` / pattern `(&.*)?` - the part of the query string *after* the `language` URL parameter (if any). This includes the `&` delimiter after the `language` URL param.

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable in the *substitution* string contains the full root-relative URL-path. We follow this with the query string that we rebuild using the backreferences as explained above, injecting `portuguese-pt` as the value of the `language` URL param (replacing any other value this URL parameter might have had).

The `NE` (`noescape`) flag is required to prevent the `&` (URL param delimiter) being URL-encoded in the response.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues, even if you change this to a permanent redirect later.